# Bash script which finds java home directory in case java_home env variable was not set? which works on different linux distributions?

Tags: java, linux, bash

I am trying to write a bash script which sets the JAVA_HOME env variable in case it is not set. The problem here is this script should be able to run on different Linux distributions such as Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL),CentOS ,Fedora ,Ubuntu. Each one of these set Java Home directory in a different path.
One solutions is that I set an os specific directory list in the script and search through all of them to find which one is a valid path. Which I don't want to do . I want a neat clean Script.

Comment: You should probably be relying on the user to set JAVA_HOME or default to whatever version of java is on their path, rather than try to set it on your own.

Comment: The script is suppose to be very user friendly. Asking user to set JAVA_HOME is the last option in case all the other options fail to set JAVE_HOME

Comment: I'm not sure you can consider Java to be properly installed if `JAVA_HOME` isn't set. That isn't (or shouldn't be) your script's problem.